# как удалить из строк лишние слова?

Tags: c#

есть файл вида:

```
egorik1903/answer/215165156
DarthBein/gifts
sZaglotomMneDetka/answer/215165156
Apple19011998
ZhenyaGreshuk/best
```

как мне получать только самое первое слово, которое идёт перед "/"? не знаю как написать регулярное выражение

Comment: дело в том, что не после каждого слова идёт "/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужны тут регулярные выражения:

```
var result = File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\in.txt")
    .Select(l =>
    {
        var slashIndex = l.IndexOf("/");
        return slashIndex != -1 ? l.Substring(0, slashIndex) : l;
    }).ToList();

result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

ну или если данных не гигабайты:

```
var result = File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\in.txt")
    .Select(l => l.Split('/')[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: какую библиотеку нужно подключить для Select?

Comment: @inkorpus `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @inkorpus `textBox.Lines = .... ..ToArray();` вместо `.ToList()`

Comment: благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @Regent SODD - Stack Overflow Driven Development.

Comment: @PashaPash хорошо, да будет так.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov вы не умеете читать linq и лямбды? или вам не нравятся тренартные операции?  Насчет тестируемости -  даже если в первый вариант добавить `File.WriteAllLines`, чтобы сравнивать эквивалентный код, то по стандартным студийным метрикам у него Maintainability Index 71 и Cyclomatic Complexity 4. А у вашего - 61 и 5.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Читабельность - субьективное понятие. Для меня читабельность кода с методами расширения и лямбдами выше. То, что для вас она ниже - ваше личное ощущение. Ине, например,Кому-то код вида `select .. from` нравится. Это все сугубо субьективно. Как и ваше восприятие "тестируемости". Для меня тестируемость - возможность написать юнит-тесты. Которую можно померять **конкретной общепринятой метрикой**. Для вас - какая-то другая, неизвестная никому кроме вас оценка (например, чем больше промежуточных переменных, тем проще отладить, тем проще "тестировать"). whom how.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov и да, говорить о тестируемости и вообще о читабельности примера в 2 строчки - не имеет смысла. Но раз вам так хочется...

Comment: @PashaPash, ок, ок. ) Жаль конечно, что на российском SO сомнения в "святограальности" LINQ ставятся в штыки. Но впрочем, ладно) Пойду-ка я лучше из этого вопроса, от греха подальше.  ))